# why cupy automatically transfer data from GPU memory to CPU memory？

Tags: python, numpy, cupy, nano

I am using nvidia jetson nano and need to use cupy and its gpu to accelerate the calculation of correlation and it works well.
But when I call the following function and its first argument's type is cp.ndarray, it costs a lot of time; if its first argument's type is np.ndarray, the code complete in a flash.

```
def peak_search(alist, begin, end):
    res = []

    for i in range(begin + 1, end):
        loop_time_start = time.time()
        if alist[i] > alist[i - 1] and alist[i] > alist[i + 1]:
            res.append(i)
        loop_time_end = time.time()
        dTime("single loop", loop_time_start, loop_time_end)

    return res
```

the results of different kind of argument is as following:

cp.ndarray:
[the first argument's type is cp.ndarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKyx5.jpg)

np.ndarray:
[the first argument's type is np.ndarray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY5GK.jpg)

It is clear that the main cost is trasferring cp.ndarray to np.ndarray, but why this happens in the above function? Is there any ways to avoid this cost?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> It is clear that the main cost is transferring cp.ndarray to np.ndarray

When you do `alist[i] > alist[i - 1] and alist[i] > alist[i + 1]` the operation is computed on the GPU but the condition is evaluated by the CPython interpreter which know nothing about the GPU. Thus CuPy need to get the information from the GPU back to the CPU to give that to CPython. This means that every iteration will cause a synchronous GPU-CPU transfer passing though a PCI/NvLink bus with a very high latency (compared to the computation performed).

In practice, this is even worse: each  of the `alist[i] > alist[i - 1]` and `alist[i] > alist[i + 1]` operations causes a CUDA kernel to be submitted to the GPU by CuPy. CuPy also needs to allocate array on the GPU memory which is a bit expensive too. All these operations cause very expensive kernel calls. Assuming the input is a 1D array, this cause few kernel calls, CUDA kernel submission, PCI/Nvlink transfer lasting at least hundreds of microsecond per element so to operate on a scalar that can be computed in (less than) few nanoseconds by the CPU (so it is >= 100_000 times slower than what it should be).

> Is there any ways to avoid this cost?

You should never compute scalar items or even small arrays on the GPU (unless the amount of computation on each item is really huge). You need to write kernels working on a large amount of items in a row (ideally 1 CUDA kernel). In fact, CuPy works exactly like Numpy when it comes to performance: you should call vectorized functions.

I think you should write first an optimized Numpy code and then try to use a GPU with CuPy. Alternatively, you could try to write directly CUDA kernel but this is pretty low-level and thus harder to do.